# Как отправить сообщение конкретному пользователю Бота? | Telegram , Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Вечер добрый.

**Я задался вопросом, как можно прислать сообщение конкретному человеку от Бота (Данный человек писал в лс боту)? Используя aiogram, python.**

Пробовал такую штуку:

```
await message.reply(owner, 'Хеллоу!')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну хранить айди юзеров в бд, извлекать и потом просто `await bot.send_message(user_id, 'сообщение')`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'текст')
```